# How can I copy the /boot/ folder and it's contents from the live USB to sda1?

Tags: boot, grub

I made school boy when trying to follow the instructions for making a bootable SD card for ArchARM. I think I have either overwritten the boot folder on my primary partition with the ArchARM files or renamed the boot folder to "mmcblk0p1".

Since restarting I just get the grub rescue prompt.

I thought I may be able to simply boot into a live instance of eOS and copy the boot folder from the USB to the hard disk of my laptop, but I am unsure if that will solve the issue.

When booted into the live instance I can see my hard disk mounted as "sda1". There is no longer a folder called boot on this drive, but there is now a folder called "mmcblk0p1" which appears to contain boot related files. "mmcblk0p1" was the partition label for the boot partition I was trying to create on the SD card I was making for my RPi using the instructions given for ArchARM.

Can anyone help me recover my eOS install? I really don't want to reinstall if possible as I have had this particular install running for about two years and have it setup just the way I like.

P.s. I may have also overwritten the /root folder, but not sure until I can get past the boot error.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event that somebody else encounters this specific scenario.

1) Create a bootable USB with eOS.

2) Boot into a live instance.

3) Choose "Try Elementary"

4) Open a terminal and navigate to media and the drive that contains your "/" directory

5) Use the command "mv /*renamedbootfolder* /boot

6) Shut down and restart

The first time I logged in after doing this non of the pantheon elemnts loaded. i restarted again and everything was back to normal.